# C++ Mistaking a string for a char

Tags: c++, string, parameters, character

I'm relatively new to C++, and having an issue passing a string. I have 2 constructors for a class, Transaction." One constructor accepts a string and a double as its parameters, while the other accepts just a string.

When I attempt to pass the lines below, I get an error, saying:

```
no matching function for call to 'Account::addTransaction(const char [14])'
```

or

```
no matching function for call to 'Account::addTransaction(const char [11], double&)'
```

I know that there's no matching function, because I'm passing a string! Here's what I'm passing in:

```
bank.getAccount(index).addTransaction("Close Account");
bank.getAccount(index).addTransaction("Withdrawal", amount_to_withdraw);
```

I don't know how to make it any more explicit that the first parameter is a string. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Adam

Updating per @g24l 's request:

Here is the Transaction Class:

```
#ifndef TRANSACTION_H
#define TRANSACTION_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Transaction {

private:
    string transType;
    double transAmount;

/*
 public constructors:
 * 1st constructor is the default constructor
 * 2nd constructor is for non-monetary transactions
 * 3rd constructor is for transactions involving money
 */
public:
    Transaction() {
        transType = "";
    }
    Transaction(string tType) {
        transType = tType;
    }

    Transaction(string tType, double tAmount) {
        transType = tType;
        transAmount = tAmount;
    }

    void setTransType(string);
    void setTransAmount(double);

    string getTransType() const;
    double getTransAmount() const;
};
#endif  /* TRANSACTION_H */
```

In the Account class, which uses dynamic memory allocation for an array of transactions, I have:

```
class Account{
private:
    Depositor depositor;
    int accountNum;
    string accountType;
    double accountBalance;
    string accountStatus;
    Transaction *transptr;
    int numTransactions; //number of transactions

public:
    // public member functions prototypes

    // Constructors

    /* Account default constructor:
     * Input:
     *  Depositor() - calls the default depositor constructor
     * Process:
     *  sets object's data members to default values
     * Output:
     *  object's data members are set
     */

    Account()
    {
        //cout << "Account default constructor is running" << endl;
        Depositor();
        accountNum = 0;
        accountType = "";
        accountBalance = 0.0;
        accountStatus = "open";
        transptr = new Transaction[100];
        numTransactions = 0;
    }
```

I'm wondering if, when I declare the array of Transactions, it fills in all of the Transactions with the default constructor parameters. When I "add" a transaction I'm really writing over the existing transaction.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but could "..." be interpreted as a char* and not actually a string?

Comment: Where is your class definition???

Comment: You say you have two constructors for a `Transaction` class, but you haven't provided their declarations.  Also, you're not directly constructing `Transaction` objects; you're invoking some separate `addTransaction` method.  Is that overloaded as well?  How are they declared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bank.getAccount.addTransaction` takes a `Transaction` as a parameter. So pass it one:

```
bank.getAccount(index).addTransaction(Transaction("Close Account"));
bank.getAccount(index).addTransaction(Transaction("Withdrawal", amount_to_withdraw));
```

Comment: That was actually the trick! Thanks @Mankarse! And thank you to all of the other answerers, as well. I learned quite a bit.

Answer (score 1):

just wrap it in a std::string

```
bank.getAccount(index).addTransaction(std::string("Close Account"));
```

Comment: Thanks @lmmilewski. Now I'm getting much closer! For some reason, though, on the 2 parameter function, it's now saying:
no matching function for call to 'Account::addTransaction(std::string, double&)'
As I'm new to c++, what does it mean by 'double&'? Does it think I'm passing an address?

Comment: double& is a type - reference to variable of type double. Remove '&' and you'll be fine. You get the error probably (I guess here) because you call the function like bank.getAccount(index).addTransaction(std::string("Withdrawal"), 5.0);  - 5.0 is rvalue and you can't get address of it, thus you get the error. Either remove '&' from double& or use variable like: double x = 5.0; bank.getAccount(index).addTransaction(std::string("Withdrawal"), x);

Comment: btw. that's all guessing - if you shown definition of your class it would be much easier to give accurate answer

Comment: Thanks! I just added my class definition. I don't have a 'double&' anywhere, which is why I don't understand where it's getting that from, as one of the constructors.

Comment: @Adam_G: You are calling `addTransaction`, not your constructor. You need to create a `Transaction` to pass in to `addTransaction` (see my answer). This answer works for one argument, because your single argument constructor is not `explicit`, and so it can be used to convert a `std::string` into a `Transaction` implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

No, `"Close Account"` *is* a pointer to a char array terminated by the NUL character - that makes it a C-style string but *not* a C++ string. If you want to force it to be a string, create one from it explicitly:

```
bank.getAccount(index).addTransaction(std::string("Close Account"));
```

(or add variants of `addTransaction` that accept a `char *` as the first argument as well, though I'd not advise that myself).